# Creating a soft drink program using arrays

Tags: java

I'm working on a soft drink program for my class, but I can't figure out why my main class is telling me that there is an error. The program is suppose to print out the following:

```
Soft drink    ID     Starting Inventory    Final Inventory    # transactions
Coke          123           100                  70                  2
Pepsi         345           50                   80                  3
CanadaDry     678           75                   83                  1
DrPepper      444           120                  130                 3
```

This is what I have so far:

SoftDrinkTester (Main Class)

```
/**
 * This program tests the functionality of a the SoftDrinkInventory class.
 * A datafile containing initial data is used to construct a SoftDrink object.
 * Then transactions are processed where each transaction contains how
 * cases are bought or sold. A function displays a report of the drink name,
 * ID number, starting inventory, final inventory, and the number of
 * transactions processed. The largest and smallest transaction value
 * is displayed.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class SoftDrinkTester {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner inventoryFile = null; // inventory data file
        Scanner transFile = null; // transaction data file
        // open the inventory initialization file
        try {
            inventoryFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data6.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found or not opened.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // open the file containing the buy/sell transactions
        try {
            transFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data6trans.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found or not opened.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // instantiate the soft drink distributorship object
        // and process the transactions by updating the inventory totals
        SoftDrinkInventory softDrinks = new SoftDrinkInventory(inventoryFile);
        softDrinks.processTransactions(transFile);
        softDrinks.displayReport();
    }
}
```

SoftDrinkInventory

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SoftDrinkInventory {

    static final int MAXSIZE = 100;     // maximum size of 100
    private String[] names;             // softdrink names
    private String[] ids;               // softdrink identifications
    private int[] startingInventory;    // starting inventory of the softdrinks
    private int[] finalInventory;       // final inventory of the softdrinks
    private int[] transactionCounts;    // number of transactions per softdrink
    private int trueSize;               // total number of softdrinks

    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * constructor  
     * 
    .
     */
    public SoftDrinkInventory() {

        initializeString(names);
        initializeString(ids);
        initializeInt(startingInventory);
        initializeInt(finalInventory);
        initializeInt(transactionCounts);

    }


    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * displayReport  
     */

    public void displayReport() {
        System.out.printf("%-22s %-16s %-23s %-23s %s %n", "Soft Drink", "ID",
            "Starting Inventory", "Final Inventory",
            "# transaction");
        for(int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
            //change "%-22s %-16s %-23f %-23f %f %n" to the below
            //and names etc. to names[i] etc.
            System.out.printf("%-22s %-16s %-23d %-23d %d %n", names[i], ids[i],
                startingInventory[i], finalInventory[i], 
                transactionCounts[i]);

        }

    }
    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * initializeInt 
     * 
     */
    private void initializeInt(int[] a) {

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = 0;
        }

    }
    /**-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     * initializeString 
     */
    private void initializeString(String[] s) {

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            s[i] = "";

        }

    }
}
```

I still need to create public processTransactions and private findID classes in SoftDrinkInventory.
The files that I am getting my names and ID's from are as follows:

for the inventory:

```
Coke       123 100
Pepsi      345 50
CanadaDry  678 75
DrPepper   444 120
```

for the transactions:

```
345   10
123   -5
345   10
678    8
444   20
444  -20
444   10
999    5
345   10
123  -25
```

I've tried asking my professor for help, but he refuses to teach us anything outside of class. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: *"...my main class is telling me that there is an error..."* What error?

Comment: "constructor SofDrinkInventory in class SoftDrinkInvtory cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: java.util.Scanner reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay close attention to the call you make to instantiate your object:

```
SoftDrinkInventory softDrinks = new SoftDrinkInventory(inventoryFile);
```

Now, observe the formal arguments that your constructor will accept:

```
public SoftDrinkInventory()
```

The problem here is that there's no constructor with a `Scanner` as a parameter (in fact, the only constructor, shown above, takes no arguments whatsoever).

As an aside:  your arrays aren't initialized.  You should initialize them with the value you expect to initialize them with.

For example:

```
private String[] names = new String[MAXSIZE];
```

Also, as a bit of food for thought:  your `initializeInt` method is useless, since Java guarantees that arrays are initialized [to a default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6); since that is setting a primitive array's values, all of the elements are already zero.

Comment: Remove the parameter from the call.  Then, you have to figure out a sane way to get the data inside of that object.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a `SoftDrinkInventory` object in

```
SoftDrinkInventory softDrinks = new SoftDrinkInventory(inventoryFile);
```

you are passing one parameter of type `Scanner, but your constructor implementation doesn't expects any parameter:

```
public SoftDrinkInventory() {
    ...
}
```

**Also**, you would like to check your arrays initialization. They are not being initialized. You should do something like:

```
startingInventory = new int[someLength];
```